# Download and use .txt file in objective-c iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, download

I am having some problems getting my code to work :(
i am trying to download .txt file from the internet and store it in my iphone for further use but it wont work :/

here is my code :

```
-(void)DownloadFile
{
    //declerations
    NSString* TheFile;
    NSFileManager* FM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //downloading file
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myfile.com/apple.txt"];
TheFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url
                                      encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                         error: nil];
//nsstring to nsdata
NSData* data = [TheFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


//saving file
[FM createFileAtPath:[DocumentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/file.txt"] contents:data attributes:nil];
}
```

DocumentsDir is defined with this function :

```
-(void)SetDocuments
{
    NSArray* doc;
    doc = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    DocumentsDir = [doc objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then i use this function assigne the file to a variable:

```
-(void)SetFile
{
   File = [[NSString alloc]
            initWithContentsOfFile:[DocumentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/file.txt"]
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            error:nil];
}
```

i would appreciate any tips or corrections etc :) thank you for your time.

Comment: What do not work? Why don't you do error checking? Report that error, if there is one.

Comment: Did you try going step by step through your "DownloadFile" method?

Comment: Anyways, why are you converting string to data? use     NSData *dat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i get no error but the file just doesn't get stored in my variable i.e. then variable File is nil.

Comment: @Jeepston i have been messing with it for days and i dont even know where the problem arises.. whether it is in the downloading or storing :/

Comment: @AntonijoDev Kragujevac :) a ti brate?

Comment: @AntonijoDev i convert to NSData because the NSFilemanager class needs NSData objects to store them as files

Comment: Thank you all for your help :) i hope i can get this to work soon

Comment: Of course you do not get an error, since you set the error parameter to nil. Returning nil is the usual way a method says: "There is an error, introspect the error arg". Passing nil to the error parameter makes it impossible to Cocoa to report an error.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to create string and than convert string to data, you can use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] to directly get data. And Amin is saying that you should pass in error argument instead of nil. You do that by declaring NSError *error; and passing it in by reference -> instead of nil pass in &error. Zagreb ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SetDocuments like this

```
-(void)SetDocuments{

    NSArray* doc;

   //doc = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   doc = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   DocumentsDir = [doc objectAtIndex:0];
}
```